# error compiling for board node MCU 1.0

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, compilation-errors

Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Serial, 115200, 4M (3M SPIFFS)"

```
In file included from C:\Users\Priyaranjan Tiwari\Documents\Arduino\007mcu_php\007mcu_php.ino:3:0:

C:\Users\Priyaranjan Tiwari\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:84:9: error: 'WiFiClient' does not name a type

         WiFiClient & getStream(void)  __attribute__ ((deprecated)) ;

         ^

C:\Users\Priyaranjan Tiwari\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:85:9: error: 'WiFiClient' does not name a type

         WiFiClient * getStreamPtr(void);

         ^

C:\Users\Priyaranjan Tiwari\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:97:9: error: 'WiFiClient' does not name a type

         WiFiClient * _tcp;

         ^

C:\Users\Priyaranjan Tiwari\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:98:9: error: 'WiFiClientSecure' does not name a type

         WiFiClientSecure * _tcps;

         ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: 2.0.0 is a very old version from 2015. the ESP8266HTTPClient.h then expected HTTPESP8266WiFi.h included before it in the sketch as you can see it in examples